# ReactJS/nextJS: Don't get access to cookie/properties after redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

In my nextJS application the user can do a login (login page), which creates a cookie with a token and redirects to a route (main page), which uses the main component.

In the Main component I'm using getInitialProps to get the cookie token. But this is only working after refreshing the page.
So right now I'm logging in and getting redirected. If I click on the button, there is no token. After refreshing the page, I do get a token.

How can I avoid this? I think I'm doing something wrong on server side...

**Login**

```
export class Login extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Form id='login' onSubmit={this._onSubmit.bind(this)}>
        // Input fields
      </Form>
    )
  }

  _onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { username, password } = this.state

    // Sends mutation request to graphQL server
    this.props.signinUserMutation({
      variables: { username, password }
    }).then(response => {
      // Returns token
      const token = response.data.token
      if (token) {
        Cookies.set('auth-token', token)
        this.props.client.resetStore().then(() => {
          redirect({}, '/main')
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**Main**

```
class Main extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps (context, apolloClient) {
    const { req } = context
    const initProps = {}

    if (req && req.headers) {
      const cookies = req.headers.cookie
      if (typeof cookies === 'string') {
        const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies)
        initProps.token = cookiesJSON['auth-token']
      }
    }

    return initProps
  }

  clickIt = () => {
    console.log(this.props.token)
  }

  render () {
    return (<Button onClick={this.clickIt.bind(this)})
  }
}
```

Comment: After you log in, can you see is cookie set with your browser developer tools? In Chome: Dev Tools > Application > Cookies

Comment: @zarcode Yes, the cookie is set at the moment clicking the login button.

Comment: Can you do console.log(document.cookie) in getInitialProps, so we can see what is output? `getInitialProps` should trigger on route change.

Comment: @zarcode I do get the authentication token as output of the console.log command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After login your cookie is saved in browser, so you should use `document.cookie` in getInitialProps to get cookie value.

As I understand this code:

```
if (req && req.headers) {
  const cookies = req.headers.cookie
  if (typeof cookies === 'string') {
    const cookiesJSON = jsHttpCookie.parse(cookies)
    initProps.token = cookiesJSON['auth-token']
  }
}
```

is using request header to get cookie value, which will happen only after you make request to the server (when you refresh page). When navigation in browser happens that code doesn't run and you don’t get cookie. Thats why you need to get your cookie directly from browser `document.cookie`.

Consider using localStorage for saving auth tokens instead cookie, it has better api.

Since `componentDidMount` is executed only in the browser, use it to take cookie value and place it in redux store:

```
componentDidMount() {
    placeTokenInReduxStoreAction(Cookies.get('auth-token'));
}
```

I assume you use [cookies-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-js)

Comment: But document.cookie only have the token directly after login. After reloading, document is not defined

Comment: Exact this is happening for me: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2528

Comment: Makes sense document is not available on the server. This is good suggestion "Consider wrapping your code in if (process.browser){} or put it in componentDidMount hook"